# Output of for combined loop and nested if is not coming out as intended for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

From a Pandas dataframe `holiday_sales_4`, I am trying to print an output of dates and its corresponding holiday type (eg: `25-Dec-2021` & `Christmas`) using if/for loop.

The output should be printed when the `Weekly_Sales` value is `True`.

The dataframe `holiday_sales_4` is as follows:

```
    Date        Weekly_Sales
0   2010-02-12  True
1   2010-09-10  False
2   2010-11-26  True
3   2010-12-31  False
4   2011-02-11  True
5   2011-09-09  False
6   2011-11-25  True
7   2011-12-30  False
8   2012-02-10  True
9   2012-09-07  True
```

and i'm trying with this code:

```
for i in range(0, len(holiday_sales_4)):
    comparison=holiday_sales_4.iloc[i]['Weekly_Sales']
    if comparison == True:
        date_of_true=holiday_sales_4.iloc[i]['Date'].strftime('%d-%b-%y')
        if (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 12) or 
            date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 11) or 
            date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 10) or 
            date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 18)):
            return_holiday="Superbowl"
        elif (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 10) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 11) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 12) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 13)):
            return_holiday="Labour Day"
        elif (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 26) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 25) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 23) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 29)):
            return_holiday="Thanksgiving"
        elif (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 31) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 30) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 27)):
            return_holiday="Christmas"
            
        print(date_of_true,'-', return_holiday)
```

The output seems to iterate the loop/if condition correctly for `date_of_true`, but not for `return_holiday`:

```
12-Feb-10 - 07-Sep-12
26-Nov-10 - 07-Sep-12
11-Feb-11 - 07-Sep-12
25-Nov-11 - 07-Sep-12
10-Feb-12 - 07-Sep-12
07-Sep-12 - 07-Sep-12
```

The expected output would be like:

```
12-Feb-10 - Superbowl
26-Nov-10 - Thanksgiving
11-Feb-11 - Superbowl
25-Nov-11 - Thanksgiving
10-Feb-12 - Superbowl
07-Sep-12 - Labour Day
```

Im  new to coding, so im sure the solution is simple, but I can't find it!

Comment: Your expected output?

Comment: i've edited my question for added clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only wants to print then you can use:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

for x,y in zip(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y'),df['Weekly_Sales']):
    if x in ['12-Feb-10', '11-Feb-11', '10-Feb-12', '18-Feb-13'] and y:
        print(x,'-','Superbowl')
    elif x in ['10-Sep-10', '11-Sep-11', '12-Sep-12', '13-Sep-13', '07-Sep-12'] and y:
        print(x,'-','Labour Day')
    elif x in ['26-Nov-10', '25-Nov-11', '23-Nov-12', '29-Nov-13'] and y:
        print(x,'-','Thanksgiving')
    elif x in ['31-Dec-10', '30-Dec-11', '28-Dec-12', '27-Dec-13'] and y:
        print(x,'-','Christmas')
```

output of above code:

```
12-Feb-10 - Superbowl
26-Nov-10 - Thanksgiving
11-Feb-11 - Superbowl
25-Nov-11 - Thanksgiving
10-Feb-12 - Superbowl
07-Sep-12 - Labour Day
```

OR

You can fix your current code by:

```
for i in range(0, len(holiday_sales_4)):
    comparison=holiday_sales_4.iloc[i]['Weekly_Sales']
    if comparison == True:
        date_of_true=holiday_sales_4.iloc[i]['Date']
        if (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 12) or 
            date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 11) or 
            date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 10) or 
            date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 18)):
            return_holiday="Superbowl"
            print(date_of_true.strftime('%d-%b-%y'),'-', return_holiday)
        elif (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 10) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 11) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 12) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 13)):
            return_holiday="Labour Day"
            print(date_of_true.strftime('%d-%b-%y'),'-', return_holiday)
        elif (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 26) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 25) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 23) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 29)):
            return_holiday="Thanksgiving"
            print(date_of_true.strftime('%d-%b-%y'),'-', return_holiday)
        elif (date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 31) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 30) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28) or 
              date_of_true==datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 27)):
            return_holiday="Christmas"
            print(date_of_true.strftime('%d-%b-%y'),'-', return_holiday)
```

**Note:** The problem is in your method is `strftime()` in this line:

```
date_of_true=holiday_sales_4.iloc[i]['Date'].strftime('%d-%b-%y')
```

- strftime changed the format of 'date_of_true' so your date_of_true become like `'25-Nov-11'` with string dtype so you can't able to compare it with `datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 25)`
- Another problem is that you are printing it`print(date_of_true,'-', return_holiday)` in end of the loop so with every iteration the value of return_holiday changes

Comment: Yeah, its a good idea to add the holiday types to the dataframe itself, but im hoping for a solution where that isn't allowed. Any idea how my if/for operation is wrong?

Comment: @Brian so you can store them in a variable if you don't wanted to store them in your dataframe or you can make another dataframe by dropping 'Holiday_type' column

Comment: @Brian updated answer..kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas That looks pretty neat. How does it know to print only when Weekly_Sales is True?

Comment: @Brian because of `df['Weekly_Sales']` is a boolean Series in your dataframe and we are iterating over it by using `zip()` function and inside the loop it knows due to `y`  iterator `and` and condition

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas I see! I'll try this out soon. However, out of curiosity, if its not too much, can you maybe identify what was the issue with my original code?

Comment: @Brian Sir updated answer...added reason that why your method is not working....kindly have a look and happy coding **:)**